# Collection rewrite unexpected behavior

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, collection, overrides

As far as I know (/knew), the following 2 snippets were pretty much equivalent:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel("reports/product_collection")
```

and

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("reports/resource_product_collection")
```

They both result in an instance of same class (`Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection`).

The problem comes when I try to rewrite the class. Here is how I did this:

```
<reports>
    <rewrite>                       
        <resource_product_collection>MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_Resource_Product_Collection</resource_product_collection>
     </rewrite>
 </reports>
```

This is where the difference appears, the first one isn't rewritten, while the second one is.

My questions are:

- Is this the intended behavior ? Why ?
- What is the difference between the 2 initial snippets ?

**Note:** This happens on Magento 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xml should look like this:

```
<reports_resource>
    <rewrite>                       
        <product_collection>MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_Resource_Product_Collection</product_collection>
     </rewrite>
 </reports_resource>
```

Comment: +1, works perfectly this way. I do have one question however, why does my code still work in one circumstance, but not the other ?

Comment: @VladPreda. The resource models are not meant to be instantiated with  `Mage::getModel`. Use `Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')`. The fact that it works I think it's a bug/feature of the `getModel` method